# Comments in Python 3.5 giving unicode error

Tags: python, syntax-error, string-literals

I am using Spyder IDE , Python 3.5, which is a part of the anaconda distribution. Given below are the first few lines of the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Sep 20 16:22:40 2016

@author: pavan
This program reads csv file from the given directory .
The input directory for this is : "C:\Users\pavan\Documents\Python Scripts\EOD from Yahoo"
The output file is "comprehensive_trend.xlsx"

"""
import pdb
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import os, glob
# Delarations
full_path = os.path.realpath(__file__)
current_directory = os.path.dirname(full_path)
directory = current_directory + "\\EOD from Yahoo\\"
#directory = "C:\\Users\\pavan\Documents\\Python Scripts\\EOD from Yahoo\\"
```

I was running this code on Python 2.7  and it was working fine. Just recently I migrated to Python 3.5 and when I execute this code, I get the following output:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 145-146: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

After wrecking my head quite a bit, I deleted this line from the comments section:

```
The input directory for this is : "C:\Users\pavan\Documents\Python Scripts\EOD from Yahoo"
```

Now the program runs correctly.

My doubts:

1. Why does this happen?
2. What is the best way to write comments in Python 3.5 to avoid these
   kind of errors?

Comment: `\U` (as in `C:\Users`) has a special meaning in strings in Python 3. Try adding an "r" directly in front of the comment to tell it that you don't want this behaviour, i.e. `r""" ... Created on ...`.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1347791/407651

Comment: Note that the "comments section" is a docstring. It is not a comment. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/33734170/407651.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've recently had a similar problem for the first time using 'multi-line' commenting, so I did some research.

['multi-line' comment in python doesn't actually exist.](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/505ba3cfc6addb000200e33c) As in, they're considered as strings (Hence why it can be used as docstrings). In fact they are treated as strings with no variable. This means the interpreter cannot ignore the 'multi-line' comments in your code and therefore any special characters need an escape `\`

Now knowing that they are treated as strings, there are two ways to keep your comments.

1. Convert the comments into single lined comments. In many IDE, multi-line conversion commenting is possible. (`Ctrl+K+C` in VScode). [This is recommended by PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments)
2. slap `r` in front of your multi-lined comment block, to indicate the all the characters in the strings following will be taken in as raw

From your code

```
r"""
Created on Tue Sep 20 16:22:40 2016

@author: pavan
This program reads csv file from the given directory .
The input directory for this is : "C:\Users\pavan\Documents\Python Scripts\EOD from Yahoo"
The output file is "comprehensive_trend.xlsx"

"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `\User` in the comments and `\U` is interpreted as a unicode literal which failed to be decoded.

use `\\User` instead.

Similarly, `\u` should be replaced with `\\u`.

P.S. Python supports multi-line string literal as docstring and the usage here is perfectly fine and recommended.