# Getting Syntax error while using comment in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

when I run python code with some comments on top of it I get syntax error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 75-76: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Mar  3 23:41:08 2021

@author: Hp
Note: Lookup copied to C:\Users\Hp\Aswin\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py)


"""
from utils import process_tweet, lookup
import pdb #used for debugging
from nltk.corpus import stopwords, twitter_samples 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import string
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
from os import getcwd
```

It's a pain to use # at every line. Please suggest me how to solve this.
My python version is - 3.8.3

Comment: Not getting any errors with the above code (Python 3.9)

Comment: What environment are you running on? Didn't get any errors on 3.8.3 for me. Plus your error is at position 139-140 which is definitely not due the comment string on top of the code. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592850/comments-in-python-3-5-giving-unicode-error

Comment: Please [edit] to include the full error traceback as that contains valuable information

Comment: it should normally not get any errors, but why is it happening in mine! ?. Somehow python is misinterpreting """ as something else

Comment: when i remove the commented line Note: Lookup copied to C:\Users\Hp\Aswin\lib\site-packages\utils\__init__.py) the error disappears.

Comment: `\U…` in the path is interpreted as an unicode escape sequence. Use a raw string (`r"""`) to prevent that.

Comment: @klaus-d this worked. Thank you!