# Docstring invalid escape sequence triggered by a display equation in latex

Tags: python, flake8

I put a latex math expression in the docstring for a function in Python. It triggers a error "W605 invalid escape sequence" which breaks flake8 checking. How to fix it?

```
"""
The test function is defined as:
\sin(\pi x)/x
"""
```

**I solved this by using double slashes now.**

Comment: Are you going to show us the code?

Comment: Can you just use `\\sin(\\pi x)/x` in your string?

Comment: Use a raw string.

Answer (score 5):

Use a raw string for the docstring

```
import math
def do_this(x):
    r"""This doc string contains a backslash \sin(x)"""
    print(math.sin(x))
```

Then flake8 will not complain anymore. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33734332/2641825) mentioning [PEP 257](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) for more details on the fact that raw doc strings are needed when they contain backslashes.