# Writing double backslash in python Docstring

Tags: python, escaping, documentation, docstring

I am writing documentations for a python package with a clear_stop_character function, in which users can provide extra stop-chars in a list. In the documentation I have written:

```py
"""
stoplist (list, default empty): Accepts a list of extra stop characters,
            should escape special regex characters (e.g., stoplist=['\\*']).
"""
```

It is crucial for the users to see the double backslash before the stop-char. However, the `help()` outcome of the built package shows:

```py
"""
stoplist (list, default empty): Accepts a list of extra stop characters,
            should escape special regex characters (e.g., stoplist=['\*']).
"""
```

So, it will be misleading for the users.
BTW, I did not find a solution based on the previous questions.
Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't Python auto escape '\' in \_\_doc\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734170/why-doesnt-python-auto-escape-in-doc)

Comment: @python_user yes, it does. But, I think the next answer  is also good. Maybe this record help the others.

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/#:~:text=quotes%22%22%22%20around%20docstrings.-,Use,-r%22%22%22raw%20triple

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\` in Python is an escape character which tells Python to interpret the character following it literally. This means that `\\` tells Python to interpret the second `\` literally, thus causing the error where the first backslash is not displayed.

The simplest solution to this problem is to use four backslashes: `\\\\`. This way, Python sees the first backslash and interprets the second one literally, printing `\`. Then, the third backslash will tell Python to interpret the fourth one literally like `\`.

Simply rewrite your code as:

```
"""
stoplist (list, default empty): Accepts a list of extra stop characters,
            should escape special regex characters (e.g., stoplist=['\\\\*']).
"""
```

Comment: And now the docstring itself is wrong when a user looks at the source file, how is this a good solution?

Comment: Typically docstrings are used to generate documentation pages for source code; any time the `__doc__` object is accessed, it will not have the four backslashes but only two, so any user-facing docs will always look correct. The source file will still have four backslashes, but this is an unavoidable consequence of backslash being used as an escape character.